# Cannot connect to 2 different remote databases using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a code like this, where `$_DB_HOST1` != `$_DB_HOST2`:

```
$dbPnt1 = new Database($_DB_HOST1, $_DB_SCHEMA1, $_DB_USER1, $_DB_PASS1);
$dbPnt2 = new Database($_DB_HOST2, $_DB_SCHEMA2, $_DB_USER2, $_DB_PASS2);

if($dbPnt1->connect())
{
    if($dbPnt2->connect())
    {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else
        echo "ERROR 2";
}
else
    echo "ERROR 1";
```

And the `Database` class is structured like this:

```
class Database
{
    // ...

    public function __construct($host, $schema, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->host = $host;        
        $this->schema   = $schema;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        if(!$this->connected)
        {
            $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);

            if($this->link)
            {
                $this->db = mysqli_select_db($this->link, $this->schema);

                if($this->db)
                {
                    $this->connected = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The problem is that it seems that I cannot connect to 2 different database hosts in the same PHP script. Is there a bug in my code that I am not seeing?

Thanks

Comment: What does it echo? Are the username/password/host/database names correct?

Comment: It looks like it should work to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i think you should return `$this->link` in your connect function. Otherwise you have `true` or `false`in your variable.

Perhaps its much easier if you check the connection in your database class and throw an error if the connection is not working.

```
class Database {
    private $link;

    private $connected;

    public function __construct($host, $schema, $username, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;        
        $this->schema   = $schema;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        if(!$this->connected) {
            $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);

            if($this->link) {
                $this->db = mysqli_select_db($this->link, $this->schema);

                if($this->db) {
                    $this->connected = true;
                    return $this->link;
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception('Database not available');
            }
            else
                throw new Exception('Connection not available');
        }
        else
            return $this->link;
    }

    // ...
}

$dbLink1 = new Database($_DB_HOST1, $_DB_SCHEMA1, $_DB_USER1, $_DB_PASS1);
$dbLink2 = new Database($_DB_HOST2, $_DB_SCHEMA2, $_DB_USER2, $_DB_PASS2);
```

If you cann some mysqli functions the first Parameter is the link. Then you have the complete Link and you can work with it. I have not tested it yet. But thats a short hint for you.

```
mysqli_query ( $dbLink1 , string $querg );
```